# Undefined offset: -1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

when I try to get the value of a dynamic input tag and execute a jquery function, I not only do not get the numeric string value of the input, but I keep getting an

```
Undefined offset: -1 error in Laravel
```

Here is the code in question:

```
foreach ($rates as $rate) {

}
echo "\n";


// This would be the index of the rate selected by the user
$selected_rate_index = count($rates) - 1;

// After the user has selected a rate, use the corresponding object_id
$selected_rate = $rates[$selected_rate_index];
$selected_rate_object_id = $selected_rate['object_id'];
```

Here is my foreach loop in the laravel blade:

```
 @foreach ($rates as $key => $rate)

    {{ $loop->index }}

    @if ($loop->first)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="{{ $rate->provider_image_75 }}" alt="">
         {{ $rate->provider }} ({{ $rate->duration_terms }})
            </td>
            <td width="20%">
                <input type="radio" class="pull-right rate-value" name="rate" value="{{ $rate->object_id }}">
            ${{ $rate->amount }} <span> <button type="submit" class="yena-btn btn yena-btn_lg btn-danger"> Add This Rate </button> </span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    @elseif ($loop->iteration == 2)

        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="{{ $rate->provider_image_75 }}" alt="">
                {{ $rate->provider }} ({{ $rate->duration_terms }})
            </td>
            <td width="20%">
                <input type="radio" class="pull-right rate-value" name="rate" value="{{ $rate->object_id }}">
                ${{ $rate->amount }} <span> <button type="submit" class="yena-btn btn yena-btn_lg btn-danger"> Add This Rate </button> </span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    @elseif($loop->last)

        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="{{ $rate->provider_image_75 }}" alt="">
                {{ $rate->provider }} ({{ $rate->duration_terms }})
            </td>
            <td width="20%">
                <input type="radio" class="pull-right rate-value" name="rate" value="{{ $rate->object_id }}">
                ${{ $rate->amount }} <span> <button type="submit" class="yena-btn btn yena-btn_lg btn-danger"> Add This Rate </button> </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    
    @endif
@endforeach
```

And lastly, here is my code for the jquery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("button").click(function(){
    var val = $("input[name='rate']:checked").val();
    alert(val);
});
</script>
```

Does anybody know what's triggering the undefined error and why I can't get the actual numeric string value of the input?  The alert value of the input tag reads something like this

```
14b35c21512c4f1b9a04e9efec1d7429
```

When it should read a shipping rate like

```
$8.73
```

Comment: What if `$rates` is empty? Then `count($rates)` is 0 and therefore `count($rates) - 1` is -1 and you access `$rates[-1]` in the next line.

Comment: Through the die dump, I can verify that the rates are indeed empty.  Not sure I follow your solution.  When I try to adjust it to [-1] it triggers the same error.  Not sure how to fix it, considering in my blade file, rates do show up, but when I try to submit it, it kicks off the error.

Comment: It's not a solution - I just pointed out why you get this error, since you asked about why you get `Undefined offset: -1` and not why your rates are an empty array, so I figured you didn't get there yet.

Comment: At this point I have no idea why the array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the object ID as the value of the radio button, which must the alphanumeric value shown in the alert.

You can add the amount in the data attribute of the radio button like below.

```
<input type="radio" class="pull-right rate-value" name="rate" value="{{ $rate->object_id }}" data-amount="{{ $rate->amount }}">
```

Then use the below jQuery code to retrieve the amount.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("button").click(function(){
       var val = $("input[name='rate']:checked").data('amount');
       alert(val);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: This part of the code functions now thanks to your suggestion, but I'm still getting an empty rates error.